# Difference between time.time() and datetime.utcnow()

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I want to know about the difference between `time.time()` and `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`. Does both returns the current UTC time?

Comment: Did you try it? The two functions return different things.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you out? If so, please consider marking one of them as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `time.time()` function **returns the number of seconds since the epoch**, as seconds. Note that the "epoch" is defined as the start of January 1st, 1970 **in UTC**. So the epoch is defined in terms of UTC and establishes a global moment in time. No matter where you are "seconds past epoch" (time.time()) returns the same value at the same moment.
You can read more about time [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html).

Regarding [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` returns the **current UTC date and time**, with tzinfo None. This is like now(), but returns the current UTC date and time, as a naive datetime object. An aware current UTC datetime can be obtained by calling datetime.now(timezone.utc)

Here is some sample output I ran on my computer, converting it to a string as well:

```
>>> import time
>>> ts = time.time()
>>> print(ts)
1583748843.6486485
>>> import datetime
>>> st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> print(st)
2020-03-09 12:14:03
```

Answer (score 4):

> Does both returns the current UTC time?

Yes and no.

The thing is how they return it.

Module `datetime` and classes in it (including `datetime` as class, which you use here) are for operating on date and time - thus they store the date/time in a structured form (**object**) and allow operations on it (methods).

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 9, 10, 4, 4, 284553)
```

While `time` module is more about straight C-like time operations. In this case: just returning timestamp (seconds from epoch) - as **float** (not a special class object).

```
>>> import time
>>> time.time()
1583748064.798787
```